# Отсутствуют изменения в файле при конфликтном слиянии

Tags: git, git-merge

Поставил git и по непонятной мне причине он отказывается показывать изменения в файле, в котором произошел конфликт при слиянии. Отсутствует `<<<<<<< HEAD` и берет он версию файла из текущей ветки.

Как это поправить?

Comment: Что в `git status`?

Comment: All conflicts fixed but you are still merging.
  (use "git commit" to conclude merge)

Comment: ну, переведите :)

Comment: пишет, что конфликтов не найдено

Comment: Конфликты исправлены. Теперь что в скобочках.

Comment: Использовать `git commit`, чтобы закончить слияние слияния, но только как мне это поможет. Мне надо взять часть изменений из ветки,  с которой сливаю и часть изменений из текущей ветки. При `git merge my-branch` он говорит мне, что есть конфликты, но по итогу он их правит автоматом, взяв при этом файл из текущей ветки, а в `git status` пишет, что конфликтов нет...

Comment: попробуйте «откатиться» и посмотреть на отличия между текущим коммитом и `my-branch`: `git diff HEAD..my-branch`

Comment: Автор, как у вас дела с этой проблемой? Решили? Подошло какое-нибудь из предложенных решений?

Answer (score 1):

для того, чтобы прервать незавершённый `merge`, можно воспользоваться, например:

```
$ git merge --abort
```

Answer (score 0):

В отличии от svn, git сообщает о конфликте при любых правках файла в обеих сливаемых ветках. При этом может оказаться что обе правки были одинаковыми, и реально конфликта нет. Но git считает что пользователя нужно известит, т.к. пользователь умнее.